# Xamarin Android deserialize local json file

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin.android, xamarin

I got a working JSON deserializer but that's a JSON file from an URL. How can I recreate this and make it work with a local JSON file? The file is in the Root of my application, next to my MainActivity.

This is the working code from the URL:

```
var client = new WebClient();
var response = client.DownloadString(new Uri("http://www.mywebsite.nl/form.json"));

List<Question> questions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Question>>(response);

foreach(Question question in questions)
{

    if (question.type == "textField") {

        var editText  = new EditText (this);
        editText.Text = "This is question: " + question.id + ".";
        editText.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        layout.AddView (editText);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it working.. Had to put my .json file in the Assets folder, set the Build Action to AndroidAsset and use the next code:

```
string response;

StreamReader strm = new StreamReader (Assets.Open ("form.json"));
response = strm.ReadToEnd ();

List<Vraag> vragen = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Vraag>>(response);

foreach(Vraag vraag in vragen)
{
    if (vraag.type == "textField") {
        var editText  = new EditText (this);
        editText.Text = "Dit is vraag: " + vraag.id + ".";
        editText.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        layout.AddView (editText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var response = File.ReadAllText("myfile.json");

List<Question> questions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Question>>(response);
```

Comment: Is your file included as Content in your app bundle?  I know this code works in Xamarin.iOS, I *assume* it works in Xamarin.Android also

Comment: Yes it is marked as Content. My total code block is this: http://pastebin.com/z4y3ZASr